# Fastest way to get picture from iOS camera to desktop "file upload" dialog?

Tags: macos, ios, camera

When I'm on OS X and on a website see a [File upload] button, half the time what I want to upload is a picture, which I would like to take right then on iOS camera. Currently this means doing the following:

- click [file upload] button
- open up iPod
- go to camera app
- snap the picture
- connect iPod to Mac with USB cable
- open iPhoto
- import the picture
- click on the imported picture
- choose "show in finder"
- drag the image from finder to the file upload dialog

Is there some way I could just somehow upload from iOS camera directly? So that it would go something like this:

- click [file upload] button
- choose "upload from iOS camera"
- open up iPod
- go to camera app (or even have it start automagically)
- click "snap & send to Mac open dialog"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you enabled photo stream on iPhone and have iPhoto/Aperture on your mac, you can try [enabling photo stream on mac](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11455). If you didn't install iPhoto/Aperture,  maybe you can try MyPhotoStream.
2. I strongly recommend [flick.](http://getflick.io/), which is really easy to use and covered all platforms. It's free and cool!
3. Share to iMessage and send to yourself after taking the photo if your iMessage on iPhone is synced with mac.

---

the geeky way: If your iPad has been jailbreaked, try sshfs in Mac's homebrew. Assume that you have installed homebrew and got root privilege of iPad. Just type

> brew install sshfs

in Mac's terminal, and then

> mkdir /Volumes/iPad  && ln -s /Volumes/iPad ~/Documents/iPad && sshfs root@youripad:/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE /Volumes/iPad

(I tried to directly mkdir in Documents and mount iPad's photo directory there but failed. It just didn't appear in the open_file_dialog.)

Last, just choose the photos you want from the open_file_dialog->Documents->iPad.

If you want to unmount your iPad from mac, type

> umount /Volumes/iPad

in your terminal.

Enjoy!

Comment: Photo streaming seems like it might be a solution, but also seems very unreliable. Photos don't always appear right after taking them. Flick is the best choice right now, but after flicking you still need to save the file and open it in the upload dialog, so not pure perfection there either. Thanks!